# Select elements in iOS?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios

I have a div with text in it. The div is *not* contentEditable.

How can I allow users to select the text / part of the text inside the div?

**EDIT:** Each char of the text is wrapped in a span tag, so i guess it's not plain text. Is it possible to select elements in iOS just like one can in a regular browser?

Comment: Umm… do nothing? Text is selectable by default.

Comment: Ask users to double tap the content.

Comment: I guess I should've noted a key point here: Each char of the text is wrapped in a span tag, so i guess it's not plain text.

Comment: @Lance: Tap and hold. Double tap is for zoom.

Comment: @Dimme: If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept...thanks btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to select content in mobile safari is to **zoom in** close to the content that you want to select and then **tap and hold** the content.